# Nodejs/Express POST request middleware unable to call next() in callback

Tags: node.js, callback, express, middleware

There is very strange behavior in Express, can't figure out, mind cracking problem.

So suppose in `req.user` I have user id and here is my middleware code.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var User = mongoose.model('User');
  User.findById(req.user, function(err, user){
    if(err) return next(err);
    res.locals.user = user;
    console.log(user);
    next(); 
  });
}
```

So it is working just fine when request type is **GET**, but if request is **POST** it just get to infinite waiting, until I receive **No data received**.

There is no issues with database nor with session: `console.log(user)` always works.

This is very very strange... I even tried to use another async function and it didn't work again for POST only requests.

```
fs.stat(__dirname + '/schemas/user.js', function(err, stat){
  next();
})
```

My conclusion is that if `next()` is being called from callback during POST request it just hangs, but who can explain me WHY???

*The original issue that brings me here was when I was trying to use passport.js deserializer which reads user from mongodb for every request, so that fails too for POST only requests.*

**configurations**

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/.bin/nodemon app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.0.0rc5", //did also tried with rc4
    "ejs": ">= 0.8.3",
    "express-partials": "latest",
    "mongodb": ">= 1.1.7",
    "mongoose": "*",
    "node-uuid": "*",
    "passport": "*",
    "passport-local": "*",
    "flashify": "*",
    "nodemon": "latest"
  }
}
```

**express configuration**

```
var app = express();
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(partials());
  app.use(express.cookieParser('Secret secret'));
  app.use(express.session());
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());

  app.use(MY_MIDDLEWARE_HERE);

  app.use(express.favicon());  
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(flashify);
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});


app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});
```

Comment: Sounds like the problem may be on the client side with the way that you're generating your POST requests.

Comment: No, it isn't the case, it will fail in case of regular form post and ajax post, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure this will have an effect, but its recommended to use `bodyParser` middleware earlier in the middleware stack.  I would put it below `cookieParser` and above passport middleware, since many authentication mechanisms need to find parameters in the body.

Comment: That actually fixed the problem! Thanks a lot, you probably saved me another week. Where did you get the recommendations on the order of middleware?

Comment: There's no hard and fast recommendations, other than making sure that middleware that "depends" on other middleware come *after*.  `bodyParser` parses the body and sets `req.body`, and a lot of other middleware expect `req.body` to exists.  If those are mounted above `bodyParser`, then `req.body` will not exist (since that middleware hasn't yet processed the request) and their requirements aren't satisfied.

Comment: Had the same problem, changing the bodyParser position fixed it.